# DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension

Tags: laravel-livewire

Estaba ejecutando una aplicación con Laravel + jetstream + Livewire.
Segui los pasos de un tutorial para obtener un CRUD Y mi sorpresa es que no me funcionaba, como en el video. No funcionaba ningún botón, ni crear nuevo, ni editar, ni eliminar.

Buscando en el inspector de errores encontré esto:
[image: Advertencia del Navegador]

¿Cómo podría solventarlo?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Esos mensajes advierten que no se podrá depurar por faltar el [mapa fuente](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map); realmente no son errores que impidan el funcionamiento de los scripts.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso, en el navegador, desde el que ejecuto la aplicacion, tenia instalada la extensión de mcAfee y me bloqueaba las ventanas emergentes. O puedes abrir el navegador en modo incognito. Que allí no están instaladas extensiones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, proporciona detalles adicionales en tu respuesta. Tal como está escrita actualmente, es difícil entender tu solución.